# Count unique values of nested fields with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have array of objects where each object looks like this:

```
{
   nestedA: {
      nestedB: {
         id: 12
      }
   }
}
```

I need count all unique ids of nestedB objects. I tried something like this:

```
_(data).countBy('nestedA.nestedB.id')
```

but it give me this result:

```
{ "8": 16, "14": 12, "16": 16, "21": 15 }
```

I guess property in quotes is id and value will be count for that id.
But my goal is got counted fields, so for result above I required got number **4** (because in data I got 4 distinct ids in data object). Can you help me edit my code to get this result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with following code:

```
_(data).groupBy('nestedA.nestedB.id').size()
```